# Error message prints twice the first time through

Tags: java, duplicates

I'm using the following code to ask a user for their height in feet and inches, and return an error message if the user's input isn't an int:

```
loop = true;
while(loop){
    if(input.hasNextInt()){
        feet = input.nextInt();
        loop = false;
        break;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter an integer.");
        System.out.print("Feet: ");
        input.nextLine();
    }
}

loop = true;
System.out.print("Inches: ");

while(loop){
    if(input.hasNextInt()){
        inches = input.nextInt();
        loop = false;
        break;
    }
    if(!input.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter an integer.");
        System.out.print("Inches: ");
        input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

The program returns the error message for feet perfectly fine:

```
Feet: f
Invalid input, please enter an integer.
Feet:
```

but the first time it returns the error message for inches, it returns it twice:

```
Inches: f
Invalid input, please enter an integer.
Inches: Invalid input, please enter an integer.
Inches:
```

This error only occurs the first time the user inputs something other than an integer.
How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Think about what `hasNextInt()` does.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the hasNextInt() is fine here. It's nextInt() not consuming the \n

Answer (score 0):

If using `else` for feet works fine, why not use it again for inches?

Changing `if(!input.hasNextInt())` to `else` should fix the problem.

Comment: using else{ still has the same problem :\

Answer (score 0):

the `nextInt` method does not consume the `\n` character after the integer.

In the second loop, when `hasNextInt` is false, it reads a line. That line will be empty, because it is reading the final `\n` from the last time.

On the second iteration of the loop, then it reads the last line that you entered, and errors again.

The fix is to always use `nextLine()` and use `Integer.parseInt(String);` to get the integer. `hasNextInt()` should still work fine though.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use Integer.parseInt(String);, would that replace the entire if/else?

Comment: replace every case of `input.nextInt()` with `Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine())`. You may have to catch some exceptions